# jquery-confirm pause script if more than one $.confirm are present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a form with submit validation.
I'dd like to add more than 1 alerts on form submit with:

```
var proceed = true;

$.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm 1',content: 'No products added. Are you sure to proceed?',
    buttons: {
                ok: {
                        text: "OK",
                        btnClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function () {
                                }
                    },
                cancel: {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        action: function () {
                            proceed = false;
                            return false;   
                            }
                        }
            }
      });

... some others checks ....

if ( !proceed ) { return false;} //EXIT SCRIPT

// IF ALL CHECKS PASSED
$.confirm({
   title: 'Final confirm',content: 'All checks are ok. Are you sure to insert?',
    buttons: {
                ok: {
                        text: "OK",
                        btnClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function () {
                                form.submit(); //SUBMIT THE FORM
                            }
                    },
                cancel: {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        action: function () {
                                // CLOSE DIALOG
                                }
                        }
           }
   });
```

but on form submit I get all of 2 `$.confirm` opens! I'd like to pause second one until I click OK on the first one.

My jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/st1cqb39/2/

Answer (score 0):

Make the `finalConfirm` function as a generic one, and call it in the `action` callback (of your empty check) accordingly.

**Here is a DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/st1cqb39/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method is ok if I've only 1 check and 1 final check. But if I've N checks and 1 final check it can be complex to implement: see my second example: https://jsfiddle.net/st1cqb39/4/